# After installation react-native-vector-icons white screen

Tags: android, react-native

Before installation the react-native-vector-icons, The project is work well.
 But ..

When I install the react-native-vector-icons, I can only see the white screen . 
It took me two days to solve this problem.
But it doesn't work. I add it like this:

> npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
>   react-native link

Build success and no error or warnning,I compared with npm website,all of the file was the same,like android/app/build.gradle setting.gradle and so on, but it doesn't work in my android phone.
Thx for any help!I'm almost broke.

Comment: version of React Native?

Comment: post your stack-trace

Answer (score 0):

You must add below line and run `react-native run-android`:

Android
Option: With Gradle (recommended)
This method has the advantage of fonts being copied from this module at build time so that the fonts and JS are always in sync, making upgrades painless.

Edit android/app/build.gradle ( NOT android/build.gradle ) and add the following:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```